# What is the "-sie" suffix meaning?

Tags: meaning, suffixes, early-modern-english

While playing Thief: The Dark Project, I noticed the use of the suffix "-sie" in some words, for example: woodsie, goodsie, treesie, etc. I struggled to find an explanation for this and since the game [uses](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Thief_(series)) [Early Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English) heavily, I figured it was some kind of "archaic" use of "-y" suffix, but I didn't find any source on this nor makes sense to me (I'm not a native speaker). Is this [pidgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin) or just a fictional word to add to the fictional universe of the game?

Examples from Thief's loading screens:

> "[...] hammers saws tear the skin of **goodsie** wood... ...and laughs at the **Woodsie** Lord."

> "In summer times do Beesie flew, maple pines and grackles coo, The grassies sweet with nectars dew, til Harvest time when Him eat you." - Pagan chant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more context, but those words appear to use the diminutive suffix ["-sie"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-sie):

> **-sie** noun suffix
> \ sē *after a voiceless consonant*, zē *after a voiced consonant or a vowel* \
> variants: *or* **-sy**
> Definition of *-sie*
> : small one : one affectionately regarded

Common words using that suffix include ["footsie"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/footsie) and ["onesie"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onesie). It is in fairly widespread use.

Comment: With that in mind, I read the quotes that use "-sie" again, and made sense to me! Thank you, I've never seen (or don't recall seeing) this form before.

Comment: Please add attributions and relevant quotes; links can become corrupted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Done, thanks. (I didn't think that the last two terms needed definitions.)

Comment: It's an affectionate diminutive. They're very common. Small things are dear things, cootchie cootchie coo.